# 20 Company cars, 4 specific models.

Tags: combinatorics

Twenty cars to be bought by a company must be selected from up to four specific models. In how many ways can the purchase be made if

a) no restrictions apply?

b) at least two of each model must be purchased?

c) at most three different models must be purchased?

I've done a and b (dots & lines method), but I'm stuck on c. Any ideas/hints?

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of ways in which **more than** three different models are purchased:

Choose one car of each model, and then choose the remaining $16$ cars freely.

So the answer for (c) is the answer you got for (a) minus $4^{16}$.

Answer (score 0):

You know how many ways there are without any restrictions, and you can calculate how many ways there are if you want at least a car of each color. Take the difference.